# Matrix.rb no such file Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, matrix, rubygems, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.2

I have ruby 1.9.2 installed:

```
alykhan@helium:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]
```

But in irb when I try to `require 'Matrix'` I get an error as shown below:

```
alykhan@helium:~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'Matrix'
LoadError: no such file to load -- Matrix
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Do i need to install a specific gem to get the Matrix lib?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use lowercase:

```
require 'matrix'
```